# Cambiar a mayuscula la inicial de cada palabra de un string con la omisión de algunas palabras arbitrarias en python

Tags: string, replace, metodos

Se pide realizar una función que reciba un string y devuelva el mismo string modificado para que cada palabra comience con mayúscula a excepción de las palabras clave 'and', 'in' y  'of'.

En general he resulto la mayor parte del problema menos dos.

- El primero se debe a que mi función al encontrarse con palabras con apóstrofe, ejem. " night's ", las detecta como dos palabras diferentes y al momento de aplicar el método `title()` regresa " Night'S " en lugar de " Night's ".
- Otro error es que al momento de usar el método `replace()` para cambiar las palabras claves que no deben comenzar con mayúscula afecta también a las palabras que inician o contengan la subcadena a sustituir, ejem. la palabra ' Anderson ' utilizando el método replace("And", "and") devuelve la palabra ' anderson ' lo cual incumple con la condición de que solo las palabras clave pueden empezar con minúscula.

El código que hice es el siguiente, también recibo consejos sobre como manejar mejor estos métodos o cuales otros me conviene utilizar para simplificar y eficientar lo mas posible mi código

```
def correct_title(txt):
    txt = txt.strip().title().replace("And", "and").replace("The", "the").replace("Of", "of").replace("In","in")
    return txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, se me ocurre esta forma alternativa de lograrlo:

```
def correct_title(title):
    
    words   = title.split()
    exclude = ['and', 'in', 'of']
    
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        if not word in exclude:
            words[index] = word.capitalize()
    
    return ' '.join(words)
    
print(correct_title("hello world and in of the night's"))
```

---

Podemos descomponer la función anterior de esta forma:

Primero, declaras dos variables: `words` que almacena lo que devuelve el método `split`. Este, corta una cadena en trozos empleando como separador el caracter especificado, que por defecto es un espacio en blanco.

Tenemos también a `exclude`, que es una lista donde defines las palabras a excluir en la capitalización.

```
words   = title.split()
exclude = ['and', 'in', 'of']
```

Bien, ya tenemos una lista con las palabras y otra con las exclusiones, entonces debemos iterar sobre cada palabra y, en cada iteración, verificar que la palabra actual no existe en la lista de exclusiones.

De ser una palabra capitalizable, entonces se aplica el método `string.capitalize` de Python sobre cada palabra y se reemplaza en la lista de palabras en su posición correspondiente:

```
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    if not word in exclude:
        words[index] = word.capitalize()
```

¡Genial! ahora tenemos una lista con las palabras procesadas, pero necesitamos una cadena. Tranquilo, `string.join` se encargará de unirlo todo como una sola cadena, empleando el caracter separador especificado (un espacio en blanco).

¿Ves como se comporta de forma inversa a `split`?

```
return ' '.join(words)
```